# Phonegap AJAX Call on Android device - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am making ajax call on Phonegap app which works perfect on browser. When i build the app and try from my device - I receive Internal Server Error 500. Any suggestions what is causing it? I added whitelist plugin and  in my config.xml

Here is my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                url : 'http://address.com/Services/methodToCall',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType : "json",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: {"count":4},
                success:function(response) {
                    $('#test').html('<h1>' + response[0].Title + '</h1>' + '<p>' + response[0].Body + '</p>');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert("error"+ e.status + '|' + e.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: **HTTP 500** errors are not related to the client side. Check your server side code.

Comment: OK, but what exactly I should look for? I mean it is working fine, when I make request from browser, or via Postman?

Comment: Are you accepting `x-www-form-urlencoded` content on server?

Comment: Have you tried hitting this url from your device's browser?

Comment: I had to install CORS plugin in my Chrome Desktop browser to get it work. On mobile browser I have to install same plugin. But Phonegap doesn't require CORS,

Comment: I think I accept x-www-form-urlencoded, because the AJAX call works from desktop browser?

Comment: I am using the latest version of PhoneGap Desktop and I build the App in the online builder, if that matters.